# How to invalidate user in CAS server

Tags: spring, single-sign-on, cas, spring-security-cas

I implement CAS server 4.0 for SSO. I have 3 apps (Spring web MVC with Spring CAS security) connect to CAS server. I configure CAS server to manage ticket by JPA and check authentication in CAS by username. Currently I'm creating forgot-password function for my apps, my issue now is how to invalidate user cookie/session on CAS server (or logout them) after password has been reset (noted that they can log in by a user and execute forgot password for another user). Can we do it with CAS? Any help will be great appreciate. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

I have cas 3.1 implemented and here is what I do:

### Controller Method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/onCompletePasswordReset.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String completeResetLicense() {
    return "redirect:j_spring_security_logout";
}
```

### Spring Security

```
<http auto-config='true' entry-point-ref="casEntryPoint">
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_ADMINISTRATORS" />
        <custom-filter position="CAS_FILTER" ref="casFilter" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/j_spring_cas_security_logout" />
        <custom-filter ref="requestSingleLogoutFilter" before="LOGOUT_FILTER" />
        <custom-filter ref="singleLogoutFilter" before="CAS_FILTER" />
    </http>
    <beans:bean id="singleLogoutFilter"
        class="org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter" />
    <beans:bean id="requestSingleLogoutFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter">
        <beans:constructor-arg value="https://cas_server:8443/cas/logout" />
        <beans:constructor-arg>
            <beans:bean
                class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler" />
        </beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/j_spring_cas_security_logout" />
    </beans:bean>
```

Comment: Thanks James, but problem is after reset they don't want to redirect

Comment: @QuanMLe, then don't redirect. Just trigger an ajax call in the background with logout.

Comment: Ok thks James, I'm trying your solution.

Comment: Sorry it didn't work, because they can log with a user id and execute forgot password for another user id.

Comment: How do you handle it in a default spring web application without CAS? In my application, access to the application login page or reset or anything will detect the session and move them to the home page.

Comment: In this situation I will provide a function to invalidate session/cookie of username parameter. With CAS having a bit of difficult because CAS take care every ticket for user authentication.